# How are bubbles formed and how do they make dough rise in bread?

Tags: fermentation

So we took in biology that carbohydrate is broken into $\ce{CO2}$ and ethanol. But all I see in my mind here is that since gas is inside the dough then the gases will try to get out expanding the dough and rising it and I know that ethanol will rise as it is baked. However I am not sure how and why are bubbles formed in the first place or how they're related to this at all and does the ethanol taste stay in bread or is it completely removed once rised?

I heard on another resource that;
"It is because air bubbles get stuck inside, and when the bread bakes, the holes appear."

How does bubble getting stuck inside lead to holes appearing? it is confusing me.

Comment: For a yeast bread, the yeast is consuming sugars in the dough and producing CO2.  Kneading the bread causes the gluten in wheat to link up and become elastic, sort of like rubber.  So the CO2 makes lots of tiny little balloons in the dough.  A similar process takes place with non-yeast breads (and cakes &c), except that the CO2 comes from baking powder or soda.  AFAIK the ethanol really isn't a big factor in rising.

Comment: So it is because of the immense collision of CO2 into the bread it breaks and goes up? If so how does that piece it collided with go away?

Comment: @jamesqf — Please follow the instructions in the comment box. Do not use comments to answer questions. This negates the model on which SE is based.

Comment: Anybody competent and/or interested in this matter will answer the question on finding it, until then you need to have some patience.

Comment: @David: If I was a food chemist, I would write an answer.  Since I am not one - just a person who bakes, and takes a reasonable interest in how the process works - my comment is simply directed at helping the OP find an answer elsewhere - something that is all too often  hindered by those poorly thought out instructions.

Comment: @jamesqf You don't need to be a food chemist! You could write your comment as an answer, I'd say

Comment: @jamesqf — The instructions are not poorly thought out. They are integral to the SE model, as you will see if you re-read the introductory tour. Their importance — and unfortunately frequent violation — is why they are emphasized in the comment box. One pays nothing to use this site, so one should abide by the rules or find a different one with a model that one prefers. Please try to help make the site better.

Comment: @David: Perhaps you (or whoever wrote those rules) might learn something from that frequent violation, which is that many people who participate here do so despite those rules, and the model they try to enforce.

Comment: What I have learned from users who answer questions in comments is that text injunctions are insufficient if others are seen to be ignoring the rules with impunity. Hence the need for human intervention. The SE model states that “moderation starts with the community itself”. I did not invent the rules, nor am I a moderator, but I understand their purpose, and I implicitly agreed to them when I joined SE. Those who wish to understand the SE model and why it differs from other models should watch this YouTube video presentation from the founder of SE: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LpGA2fmAHvM.